# End salloc job from inside the job

Tags: slurm

I want to separate allocation of the nodes and running commands on the allocated nodes but do not want to manually `scancel` them once I'm done. I'd like the allocated node to remain allocated until I run a bunch of commands on them and for the job to terminate at the end of the commands. Is this possible? I believe `srun` has `--jobid` option which lets you run things on an already allocated job but I'm not sure if job ends after `srun` or not.

Answer (score 0):

To end an allocation from inside the job you can issue the `scancel` command
in the shell of the allocation (submission script, or interactive session)

```
scancel $SLURM_JOB_ID
```

This will effectively terminate the job. It will also work if you use the allocated resources by `SSH`ing to the node provided [pam slurm adopt](https://slurm.schedmd.com/pam_slurm_adopt.html) is configured. It will then terminate your SSH session.

If [pam slurm adopt](https://slurm.schedmd.com/pam_slurm_adopt.html) is not configured, and you have only one job of yours in the node, you can run something like

```
 squeue -h --me --nodelist $(hostname -s) --format %i | xargs scancel
```

to retrieve the job ID from the compute node and cancel the job from there. This will not terminate your SSH session though.

Comment: thanks but if I do the allocation with `salloc --noshell` then `$SLURM_JOB_ID` won't be defined when I later manually run something on the allocated device. right? Does `srun --jobid` also pass all env variables? Maybe I should do `srun --jobid XXX bash -c "scancel $SLURM_JOB_ID"`

Comment: It will if `slurm_pam_adopt` is properly configured and you access the allocated device with SSH. `srun --jobid XXX bash -c "scancel $SLURM_JOB_ID"` could work but you then must probably escape `\$SLURM_JOB_ID`, and maybe use `--overcommit` . But then I do not see the point as you need to lookup the jobid anyway so this seems more difficult than `scancel XXX`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separate the allocation of the nodes from the execution (in an interactive way), you could do the following:

1. Allocate the nodes with `salloc <options> bash`. For instance:

   `salloc -N 10 --exclusive --partition=cpu bash`
2. Run your commands with `srun` (as foreground or background processes, as you wish). They will be tight to your allocation.
3. When you are done, just exit the session (`CTRL + d`):

   - Each srun child process still running in background will be terminated
   - Closing the session will release the slurm allocation